# Accessing windows service from web

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows

My windows machine have 172 services going on currently .However when i try to access my windows services through web (Asp.net c#) I am getting only 143 services.And my service is not  listed.can any one please suggest a way to run my service from web?thank you.

```
        string strServiceName = param;
        string lblStatus = "";
        string Status = "Undefined";
        string strStatus = string.Empty;
        System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController[] services = null;
        try
        {
            strStatus = "Undefined";

            services = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GetServices();
            for (int i = 0; i < services.Length; i++)
            {
                if (services[i].ServiceName == strServiceName)
                {
                    strStatus = services[i].Status.ToString();
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblStatus = ex.Message.ToString();
        }
        Status = strStatus;
```

Comment: What's common about the services that are returned and what's different about your service?

Comment: which type of service you find in listed services ?

Answer (score 0):

The account running your web-sites has no permission showing the status of those 29 missing services.

You can use

```
sc.exe sdshow serviceName
```

to show the security descriptor for your service. If you compare the descriptor with one service that your code can see, you should see a difference.

You can alter the security descriptor using

```
sc.exe sdset serviceName ...
```

But you need to figure out the security descriptor language first.